# Вывод нескольких значений в таблице как одно

Tags: php, mysqli

Есть база данных, в которой 4 таблицы. Таблицы имеют следующие поля:

| Артикул | Номенклатура | Цена |
| --- | --- | --- |

Содержимое в таблицах = спарсенные данные с сайтов. На всех сайтах есть одна и та же номенклатура, на всех сайтах записана она по разному и артикулы естественно, тоже.

Суть вопроса: хочу выводить эти данные на страничке, забивая в поиск например "Samsung S10", к каждой из таблиц уходил запрос на поиск данной номенклатуры и возвращал ее цену. При этом, чтобы название номенклатуры выводилось например из 1 таблицы, к которой обратились. Вывод на сайте в формате:

| Номенклатура | Цена из таб. 1 | Цена из таб. 2 | Цена из таб. 3 | Цена из таб. 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Samsung S10 | Цена 1 | Цена 2 | Цена 3 | Цена 4 |

То есть, нужен своеобразный поиск по словам в БД, и после вывод только 1 названия номенклатуры и цен ко всем найденным. Подскажите, как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Лучше - сильно закопаться в математику и лингвистику, иначе мало толка выйдет.
Вам нужно решить задачу "нечеткого поиска". (текст в кавычках - гуглится, куча математики гарантирована).

Answer (score -1):

А зачем тебе 4 таблицы для товаров, если они одинаковые по структуре?
Можно сделать одну таблицу и добавить поле site, в котором храниться информацию о сайте, с которого был взят товар.

Чтобы получить результат поиска по названию, можно использовать оператор LIKE в SQL

Comment: Вам джоины отключили? или такой совет для того чтоб автор очень быстро уткнулся в производительность бд?

Comment: А причем здесь JOIN, если задача сводиться к поиску товара в рамках одной таблицы? Зачем плодить таблицы (Это оправдано при шардировании, но в вопросе ничего не сказано про объемы данных) ? Вы в проектах для каждого пользователя отдельную таблицу делаете?

Comment: Потому что вы пытаетесь переложить задачу по поиску с БД на прикладной ЯП. И тут же возникает новый вопрос, а точно логику связей нужно перекладывать на внешний ЯП, в этом случае уже по сотне тысяч товаров подгрузка нового "магазина" превратится в ад для сервера? Как вы уже сказали что за задачу решает ТС - неизвестно, но по описанию задачи - на малых данных проблемы не будет с любым решением, а на больших данных - проблемы будут либо с добавлением нового магазина, либо с объемами join в пределах таблицы... и вот тогда уже от шардирования не отвертется никак

Comment: Я все равно не понял, что не нравиться в ответе. Если человеку нужен поиск по млрд записей, есть ElasticSearch, если у человека слишком большие объемы данных, есть шардирование. В вопросе нет ничего, что связанно с производительностью и большой нагрузкой. Предполагаю, что человек только знакомиться с архитектурой БД. Человек написал, что у него в одной БД 4 таблицы, для чего 4 таблицы в рамках одной БД не понятно. При этом многие, кто начинает проектировать БД, думают о том, почему бы не сделать "для каждого пользователя отдельную таблицы", что не верно. Считаю, что вы переусложнили вопрос

Comment: Ааа, вы об этом... :) то что это не ответ а максимум комментарий или уточнение к вопросу... :) а ответ на этот вопрос будет размером примерно с эту статью https://habr.com/ru/post/114997/